# Jquery: Ajax Retrieving Unicode Data from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i managed to SAVE unicode data using jquery ajax call, but when i try to retrive back using jquery and ajax i cant pass array of unicode data using json_encode, the unicode data were changed to NULL

from my php page, this one give back the same data

```
$detailsArr='有自動設好了哦…';
echo $detailsArr;
```

in my jquery page

```
success: function(msg){
    alert(msg)
}
```

if i add json_encode, the result in my jquery call is NULL

```
$detailsArr=array('有自動設好了哦…');
$retVal=json_encode($detailsArr);
echo $retVal;
```

in my jquery page

```
success: function(msg){
    var ajxGlobalData=eval("(" + jsonText + ")");
    alert(ajxGlobalData)
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `utf8_encode` like

```
$detailsArr='有自動設好了哦…';
echo utf8_encode($detailsArr);
```

More on utf8_encode here: [PHP: utf8_encode - Manual](http://in.php.net/utf8_encode)

Comment: thanks Anush, but $detailsArr='有自動設好了哦…'; was already correct to begin with, tried it anyway -- but still the return value to the jquery page is NULL, i was hoping for another way to send back ARRAY data back to the jquery page